# MySQL: order by value from second table, use default if value not set

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, subquery, union

This takes place inside WordPress, but it's a general MySQL question.

There are two tables, one of which contains posts, the other metadata, linked by ID.

```
post_title | ID     post_id | meta_key | meta_value
-----------+---     --------+----------+-----------
title      | 1      1       | key_1    | aaa
-----------+---     --------+----------+-----------
title      | 2      1       | key_2    | bbb
                    --------+----------+-----------
                    1       | mykey    | 1
                    --------+----------+-----------
                    2       | key_n    | ccc ddd
```

I'm trying to order results on some column value, which might not be set for all rows. Basically, I want to see rows with this column/value pair set first, followed by all the others. Each post might have some metadata associated with it, based on `meta_key` and `meta_value` pairs. There may be more keys for a single post and they need not include the one I want to sort by.

The problem is that using a MySQL query with a `WHERE meta_key = mykey` will exclude all the posts where this key doesn't exist. So what I need is a way to display a default value for all those posts, where this meta key doesn't exist.

**First step**: It's easy to select all rows with a certain meta_key:

```
SELECT
    p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_type, p.post_date, m.meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id 
WHERE
    m.meta_key = 'mykey'
```

**Second step**: how do I select all the rows where this meta_key doesn't exist?

Here's what I mean, but this is probably a bad solution:

```
SELECT
    p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_type, p.post_date, "some_default"
FROM wp_posts AS p
WHERE
    p.ID NOT IN (
        SELECT
            p.ID
        FROM wp_posts AS p
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id 
        WHERE
           m.meta_key = 'mykey'
    )
```

**Third step**: show combined results. This could be a `UNION` of both queries above.

I'm sure there must be a better sulution. What's more important, I don't know how to specify additional paramaters – e. g., first find all posts with some given meta key, or title, or category etc. and then order by said `mykey` as layed out above.

**FINAL EDIT**

***If anyone's interested, here's the final solution in context. RedFilter's answer made it possible, thanks again.***

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.post_title, p1.post_type, p1.post_date, m1.meta_value AS meta1, meta2
FROM wp_posts AS p1
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m1 ON m1.post_id = p1.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tr0 ON tr0.object_id = p1.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt0 ON tr0.term_taxonomy_id = tt0.term_taxonomy_id 
LEFT JOIN wp_terms AS t0 ON tt0.term_id = t0.term_id 
LEFT JOIN
(   
    SELECT
        p.ID, IF (m.meta_value = 'on', 1, 0) AS meta2
    FROM wp_posts AS p
        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m 
            ON p.ID = m.post_id 
            and m.meta_key = 'mykey'
) as extra 
    ON extra.ID = p1.ID
WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND m1.meta_key = 'some-other-meta-key'
    AND p1.post_type IN ('post', 'some-custom-post-type')
    AND tt0.taxonomy = 'some-taxonomy' 
    AND t0.term_id = 'some-id' 
ORDER BY meta2 DESC, meta1 ASC, p1.post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_type, p.post_date, 
    ifnull(m.meta_value, 'default val') as meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id 
    and m.meta_key = 'mykey'
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Now I only have to figure out how to combine this with other conditions, e. g. get this `mykey` values only for rows with some _other_ `meta_key` or possibly another join with a third table.